# Can istio circuit breaking be defined with the client configuration rather than the server configuration?

Tags: istio

In **istio** a circuit breaker must be defined as a `DestinationRule` (https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#circuit-breakers). This is okay, but we might want to define different thresholds for each client and I would prefer the definition to be stored in the client's configuration.

As we are in a software company with organisational structures and configuration is in different places it would be nice for us to own this, and store it with the client config.

- Is this possible?
- Is it possible to configure circuit breaking on a client by client basis?
- If the answer to the above two questions is no, why should I not have this? (Am I asking for something I shouldn't need?)

Comment: What you mean by each client? each service? What you mean by configure circuit breaking on a client by client basis? Per envoy [doc](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.5.0/intro/arch_overview/circuit_breaking) `Each circuit breaking limit is configurable and tracked on a per upstream cluster and per priority basis.`

Answer (score 0):

Istio will look for DestinationRules in the following order:

1. consumer namespace
2. provider namespace
3. config root namespace, which is usually "istio-system".

That way you can have different circuit breaking configurations per client by placing them into the corresponding client namespaces.
This assumes of course that the clients run in different namespaces.